# kafka disaster recovery with wmware disk replication

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

We are looking for some methods to handle disaster recovery of a kafka cluster. We know there are some tools like Confluent replicator or Apache MirrorMaker. But we dont want to spawm another kafka cluster or handle topic offsets by ourself.

1. is it possible to take a snapshot of the disks of a kafka cluster and respawn that virtual machine(s) in another data center ? We will also get the disk snapshot of zookeeper cluster.
2. We are aware of we may lose some data but is that cluster will be a healty cluster? Has anyone tried this method before?

We are using NAS storages and we can replicate entire disk using wmware disk replication utility.

Links about wmware replication utility.

[How Does vSphere Replication Work?](https://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2011/10/how-does-vsphere-replication-work.html)

Thanks

Comment: Any conclusion ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Docker deployment to create "snapshots" and respawn then on other cluster.